# Jquery toggle poll, animate based on answers

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

So I am working on building a sort of animated poll.
As you click each answer on each question, a corresponding circle animates to the right.

The tricky part for me is, after the first question....lets say someone clicks 'Answer1' from the first question, then clicks 'Answer1' on the 2nd question, but then clicks 'Answer2' on the second question..instead of the inital circle animating BACK to it's original size,(as I have defined) I need it to animate down to a percentage so that both circles are now equal since one was selected in the previous question. Sort of like toggling.

Make sense?

This part of it is a bit tricky for me as I am just delving into JS/Jquery. Any help, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the JS I have written for Question1.

As you can see, i have the circles animating back to 80px just for Question1...but I know for the rest of the questions, that needs to be configured by percentages somehow(which is where I get stuck)

```
/*myClick function - quiz1*/
function myClick() { /*answer1*/
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('deactive');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.circle1').animate({
                width: "+=3.0%",
                height: "+=3.0%"
            });
            percentage.html(1);
        }
        if ($('ul li:nth-child(3)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle2').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
            percentage2.html(0);
        }
          if ($('ul li:nth-child(4)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle3').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
           percentage3.html(0);
        }
    }
 }); /*answer2*/
 $('ul li:nth-child(3)').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('deactive');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.circle2').animate({
                width: "+=3.0%",
                height: "+=3.0%"
            });
          percentage2.html(1);   

        }
        if ($('ul li:nth-child(2)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle1').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
            percentage.html(0); 

        }
          if ($('ul li:nth-child(4)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle3').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
           percentage3.html(0); 
        }
      }
    }); /*answer3*/
    $('ul li:nth-child(4)').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') === false) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('deactive');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('deactive');
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('.circle3').animate({
                width: "+=3.0%",
                height: "+=3.0%"
            });
             percentage3.html(1); 
        }
        if ($('ul li:nth-child(2)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle1').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
            percentage.html(0); 

        }
          if ($('ul li:nth-child(3)').hasClass('deactive')) {
            $('.circle2').animate({
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px"
            });
            percentage2.html(0); 

            }
        }
    });
  }
```

I know this is a bit intensive, so any type of help, hints or whatever would be really great.
Thanks!

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GregWebBandit/UVvyV/)